# How to write text on the bottom of the screen in HTML / CSS?

Tags: html, css, position, screen, footer

I want to put a single line of text on the bottom of the screen, but it is important not to cover other elements of the page. I tried the `<footer>` tag, but unfortunately it covers the content. The code, which I found reading an other question:

```
footer{
    position: normal;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
}
```

So what I am looking for is a line of text which appears only if I reached the bottom of my page if the page is "longer" than the monitor's height, or stays at the bottom of the screen (as footer does) if the height of the page is less or equal with the height of the monitor.

Comment: What you're looking for is a "sticky footer", of which there are numerous examples available on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `position: absolute;` You may want to rethinking your layout using a *flexbox* technique. Check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/